# Pyomo: define objective Rule based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

In a transport problem, I'm trying to insert the following rule into the objective function:

*If a supply of BC <19,000 tons, then we will have a penalty of $ 125 / MT*

I added a constraint to check the condition but would like to apply the penalty in the objective function.

I was able to do this in Excel Solver, but the values ​​do not match. I've already checked both, and debugged the code, but I could not figure out what's wrong.

Here is the constraint:

```py
def bc_rule(model):
    return sum(model.x[supplier, market] for supplier in model.suppliers \
                                       for market in model.markets \
                                       if 'BC' in supplier) >= 19000  
model.bc_rules = Constraint(rule=bc_rule, doc='Minimum production')
```

The problem is in the objective rule:

```py
def objective_rule(model):
    PENALTY_THRESHOLD = 19000
    PENALTY_COST = 125

    cost = sum(model.costs[supplier, market] * model.x[supplier, market] for supplier in model.suppliers for market in model.markets)

    # what is the problem here?
    bc = sum(model.x[supplier, market] for supplier in model.suppliers \
                                       for market in model.markets \
                                       if 'BC' in supplier)
    if bc < PENALTY_THRESHOLD:
        cost += (PENALTY_THRESHOLD - bc) * PENALTY_COST

    return cost

model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize, doc='Define objective function')
```

I'm getting a much lower value than found in Excel Solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition (`if`) depends on a variable in your model.

Normally, `if`s should never be used in a mathematical model, and that is not only for Pyomo. Even in Excel, if statements in formulas are simply converted to scalar value before optimization, so I would be very careful when saying that it is the real optimal value.

The good news is that if statements are easily converted into mathematical constraints.

For that, you need to add a binary variable (0/1) to your model. It will take the value of 1 if `bc <= PENALTY_TRESHOLD`. Let's call this variable `y`, and is defined as `model.y = Var(domain=Binary)`.

You will add `model.y * PENALTY_COST` as a term of your objective function to include the penalty cost.

Then, for the constraint, add the following piece of code:

```
def y_big_M(model):
    bigM = 10000 # Should be a big number, big enough that it will be bigger than any number in your 
                 # model, but small enough that it will stay around the same order of magnitude. Avoid 
                 # utterly big number like 1e12 and + if you don't need to, since having numbers too 
                 # large causes problems. 
    PENALTY_TRESHOLD = 19000
    return PENALTY_TRESHOLD - sum(
        model.x[supplier, market]
        for supplier in model.suppliers
        for market in model.markets
        if 'BC' in supplier
    ) <= model.y * bigM
model.y_big_M = Constraint(rule=y_big_M)
```

The previous constraint ensures that y will take a value greater than 0 (i.e. 1) when the sum that calculates `bc` is smaller than the `PENALTY_TRESHOLD`. Any value of this difference that is greater than 0 will force the model to put 1 in the value of variable `y`, since if `y=1`, the right hand side of the constraint will be `1 * bigM`, which is a very big number, big enough that `bc` will always be smaller than `bigM`.

Please, also check your Excel model to see if your if statements really works during the solver computations. Last time I checked, Excel solver do not convert if statements into bigM constraints. The modeling technique I showed you works for absolutely all programming method, even in Excel.

Comment: Sorry for the late...I had to study a bit about Big M.

The solution you proposed was really what I was looking for.

However, Pyomo still complains about the objective function, because the solver used does not accept quadratic functions. I noticed that this problem is related to the multiplication of the variable y by the sum of BC:

`cost += PENALTY_COST * model.y * (PENALTY_THRESHOLD - sum(bc))`

Although I change the solver to **cplex**, the returned value does not match the expected value.

Comment: You can only use multiplication in a LP model when you multiply parameter time parameter or parameter time variable. Multiplying variable time variable is not accepted in any kind of LP model, and that's probably what makes your problem quadratic. Perhaps, there is a way to work around it.